# How to make the text of selected radio button label bold using jQuery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to  make the text of selected radio button label bold using jQuery or javascript. I don't know how to triggerthe function I wrote.

```html
<div class="row field">
  <div class="radios">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" checked>Male</label>

    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female">Female</label>

  </div>
```

```js
$("input[name=gender]:radio").change(function () {
 var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();

 switch(gender){
  case "Male":
  $(":radio[value=Male]").css("font-weight", "bold");
  break;
    
  case "Female":
  $(":radio[value=Female]").css("font-weight", "bold");
  break;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use pure css for that, no need for javascript:

```css
input:checked ~ span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="row field">
  <div class="radios">
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male" checked><span>Male</span></label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="female"><span>Female</span></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Node that I added a span element to wrap the text (which should be bold).